# Adding 0 at starting of int value in c

Tags: c, int

I am in WinCE7 and to get the current time, I am using `GetLocalTime(&systemTime);`. This function gives the value of current time. Now if the milliseconds is `81`, it displays it as `81` due to which the error occurs when I subtract two time values. For ex: `time1 : 12:34:13:851`  &    `time2: 12:34:14:81`. Now I need to subtract seconds and milliseconds. So using sprintf, I am extracting seconds and milliseconds and putting them in `time1` & `time2` :

```
sprintf(time1,"%d.%d",systemTime.wSeconds,systemTime.wMilliseconds) 

sprintf(time2,"%d.%d",systemTime.wSeconds,systemTime.wMilliseconds)
```

I am converting `time1 & time2` into float using `atof`.Now time1 is `13.851` and time2 is `14.81`. The milliseconds of time2 is actually `081` but it displays `81` so while subtracting it consider it as `810` which gives wrong values.

```
time2-->  14.810              14.081
time1-->  13.851              13.851
          --------          ---------
result     0.959(wrong)        0.23(correct)
```

So to remove this error I thought of counting the digits of milliseconds and if it is `2` then add `0` at starting. So I did:

```
double digits = (floor (log10 (abs (milliseconds))) + 1); //calculate digits
if(digits == 2) //if milliseconds contains 2 digits, we need to add 0 at starting
{
  sprintf(newMS,"0%d",milliseconds); //adding 0 to milliseconds
  finalMilliseconds = atoi(newMS);  //newMS is in char so converting it into integer and storing the value in finalMilliseconds
}
```

The problem occurs here. Lets say `milliseconds = 18`, so `newMS = 018` but `finalMilliseconds` is again `18`.

Please suggest any other way of conversion or any other way of adding 0 at starting

Comment: Try `sprintf(time1, "%d.%03d", systemTime.wSeconds, systemTime.wMilliseconds)` .

Comment: yeah but when I'll convert time1 to int using `atoi` it will remove 0.

Comment: @Andrew `atoi` converts to integer, so anything after the decimal point is ignored anyway

Comment: @user3386109 suggests the correct thing if you use `atof` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`SYSTEMTIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from MSDN:

> It is not recommended that you add and subtract values from the
> SYSTEMTIME structure to obtain relative times. Instead, you should
>
> Convert the **SYSTEMTIME** structure to a **FILETIME** structure.
> Copy the resulting **FILETIME** structure to a **ULARGE_INTEGER** structure.
> Use normal 64-bit arithmetic on the **ULARGE_INTEGER** value.

The [example here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26051) will give you some idea on how to get started.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me the simplest solution is to borrow what you need.

You already have integers.  If you're subtracting two `systemTime` values, `t2` from `t1`, say,

```
if( t1.wMilliseconds < t2.wMilliseconds ) {
    t1.wMilliseconds += 1000;
    t1.wSeconds--;
}
```

Or, just perform the subtraction.  If the result's `wMlliseconds` is negative, adjust as above.

Take care to ensure `t1 > t2`, though.  You don't want `-1.25 = 0.0 - 0.75`.

Instead of putzing with strings, if you want a float, make one:

```
double time1 = t1.wSeconds + 0.001 * t1.wMilliseconds;
```

C does the conversion for you.  It's faster, more direct, and less error-prone than going through strings.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of dealing with these marvels of lost leading or trailing zeroes (found in time and longlat), is to right pad the string with say four zeroes .i.e your newMS+"0000", and take the leftmost four characters.
You then have a number (as text) ranging from "0000" to "9990".
Put a "1" in front of it, then you can easily and unambiguously convert to an integer between 10000 and 19990.
Then you can add and subtract as you like.

Clumsy? Yes indeed :)  But I have had to do weird tricks like this when GPS longitude readings go from 11.59(funny numbers) to 12.00